# How to drop and create indexes in mongoose mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have been trying to reset the unique key indexes while importing the data as shown below:

```
const importData = function() {
   UserLocation.collection.dropAllIndexes((err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.trace(err);
      return;
    }
    UserLocation.collection.createIndex({
     Adfrom: 1,
     Adpto: 1
    }, {
     unique: true
    });

    fs.createReadStream(`${__dirname}/../data/import-data.csv`).pipe(parser);
   });
 };
```

Its working fine in my local environment but when i deploy this code iam getting mongodb connection error because of dropIndex.

```
Error:
Mongoose default connection to mongodb://localhost:27017/userlocation disconnected
Mongoose default connection error: MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
```

How to fix this issue.

Please help !

Thanks

Comment: can you add the error log?

Comment: Is it your mongo server is running. Can you check the log of mongo server too. Looks like mongo disconnection happened.

Comment: yes, it's running. when i do only import without drop/create indexes it's working without any errors. i guess problem is with Model.collection.dropAllIndexes and Model.collection.createIndex

Comment: use dropIndexes()(As per mongodb manual https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.6/tutorial/remove-indexes/#remove-all-indexes). Is there a function with dropAllIndexes?

Answer (score 1):

You can drop index by

```
db.collection.dropIndex("//field of which you want to drop index")
```

Or you can use the index specification document

```
db.collection.dropIndex( { "//field of which you want to drop index" : -1 } )
```

It will drop index of the field with value -1.

and collection will be the name of your table,

for eg.

```
db.pets.dropIndex( { "cat" : -1 } )
```

Simirlarly for creating index, you can have a quick glance at [Create Index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/).

You can run these commands in your mongo shell.

Comment: i can't use db.collection in mongoose model object, it should be UserLocation.dropIndex() some thing like this

Comment: Yeah these commands are for your mongo shell and not to be included in your model file.
I proposed this considering you may need to drop index in certain situation and not everytime.

Answer (score 1):

```
const schema = new Schema({ name: { type: String, unique: true } });
const Customer = mongoose.model('Customer', schema);
await Customer.collection.createIndex({ age: 1 }); // Index is not in schema
// Will drop the 'age' index and create an index on `name`
await Customer.syncIndexes();
```

You need to sync indexes. Check out this source : https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.syncIndexes